# How to create a custom toolbar for SyntaxHighlighter 3.0.83?

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntaxhighlighter

I am trying to create a custom toolbar for SyntaxHighlighter 3, but have been unable to figure out how to do so. I've seen custom toolbars before but only for version 2. I don't care if it is either a text-based or image-based toolbar so long as it contains the following items: collapse/expand, copy to clipboard, view source, print, and about. I know how to configure the text that the item displays, but am unable to display anything more than the default about/help item. I looked at the source code, but was unable to figure out how to reference the item in css.

How would I go about creating a custom toolbar that is similar to the one seen [here:](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2009/06/syntaxhighlighter-revised-again-works-on-its-own-once-again/)

Thanks in advance!